# Computer won't boot when I have 2 ram sticks in

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, ramdisk

I recently grabbed two corsair ddr4 16gb ram sticks and installed them both, and my computer would just cycle on and off without booting.  I looked up the possible issues and tried starting it with only one stick and it boots fine in one slot, but in the other it has the same cycling issue.  I have a gigabyte b150m-dv3 motherboard and an Intel i9 8950(I think... Something like that.) Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you toggle Dual Channel mode in the BIOS?

Comment: Where in the bios would I find that? I tried looking for it, and I managed to get the one card to at least run at 3600, and also set xmp, but I didnt see any settings about dual channel mode. The bios is gigabyte. I have f22 installed

Answer (score -1):

looks like a motherboard issue, check for updates on the manufacturer website and update if needed. Reset BIOS to defaults and then install the memory.
can you confirm that the RAM is not on the supported list for her motherboard?
cheers

Comment: It should be supported. This motherboard has a limit of 32gb, but I'm not going over that. Also I checked on the listed specs and it does support dual channel ram... It only has two slots, not 4 though.

Comment: @Travand  "It should be supported." - what does this mean?